# How to unzip .usdz file in python?

Tags: python, zip, usdz

Is there a way to unzip a .usdz file in python? I was looking at the [`shutil.unpack_archive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive), but it looks like I can't use that without an existing function to unpack it. They use zip compression, just have a different file extension. Would just renaming them to have .zip extensions work? Is there a way to "tell" shutil that these are basically .zip files, something else I can use?

Running the Linux `unzip` command can unpack them, but due to my relative unfamiliarity with shell scripting and the file manipulation I'll need to do, I'd prefer to use python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a couple ways.

Use `shutil.unpack_archive` with the `format="zip"` argument, e.g.

```
import shutil

archive_path = "/path/to/archive.usdz"
shutil.unpack_archive(archive_path, format="zip")

# note you can also pass extract_dir keyword argument to
# set where the files are extracted to
```

You can also directly use the [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) module:

```
import zipfile

archive_path = "/path/to/archive.usdz"
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(archive_path)
zf.extractall()

# note that this extracts to the working directory unless you specify the path argument
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! Wasn't real clear on how that parameter worked before.